# New Command 2 Apple Push Notification Not sending multiple alerts

Tags: ios, command, apple-push-notifications, push

I am trying to implement the new 'Command 2' push notification in Java and cannot have it push multiple alerts. First alert is pushed successfully. Please help if you can spot any issue on this code

Apple specs
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1

```
for (DeviceApps deviceApps : deviceAppsList) {
outputStream.write(getByteArray(deviceApps, pushAlert));
}


private byte[] getByteArray(DeviceApps deviceApps, PushAlert pushAlert) {

ByteArrayOutputStream dataBao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Write the TokenLength as a 16bits unsigned int, in big endian
dataBao.write((byte)1);
 dataBao.write(intTo2ByteArray(32));
dataBao.write(deviceTokenAsBytes);

// Write the PayloadLength as a 16bits unsigned int, in big endian
 dataBao.write((byte)2);
dataBao.write(intTo2ByteArray(payLoadAsBytes.length));
dataBao.write(payLoadAsBytes);

// 4 bytes. Notification identifier
dataBao.write((byte)3);
dataBao.write(intTo2ByteArray(4));
dataBao.write(intTo4ByteArray(random.nextInt()));

// 4 bytes Expiration date
dataBao.write((byte)4);
dataBao.write(intTo2ByteArray(4));
dataBao.write(intTo4ByteArray(pushAlert.getUtcExpireTime()));
LOG.error("UtcExpireTime="+ pushAlert.getUtcExpireTime());

// 1 bytes Priority
dataBao.write((byte)5);
dataBao.write(intTo2ByteArray(1));
dataBao.write((byte)10);


//Frame Info
bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bao.write((byte)2);
byte [] data = dataBao.toByteArray();
bao.write(intTo4ByteArray(data.length));
LOG.error(" data.length "+data.length);
bao.write(data);

return bao.toByteArray();               
}


Support Methods
private static final byte[] intTo4ByteArray(int value) {
return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();
}

private static final byte[] intTo2ByteArray(int value) {
int s1 = (value & 0xFF00) >> 8;
    int s2 = value & 0xFF;
    return new byte[] { (byte) s1, (byte) s2 };
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a library that already implements the APNS functionality like http://code.google.com/p/javapns/?

Comment: They do not have this implemented. I checked the source code.

Comment: I tested with the javaapns code a while back and it did work... I based my own implementation on some of what I saw there... The implementation itself didn't meet my particular needs though.

Comment: Javaapns works for old commands (0 and 1) but they have not implemented  the new one - 2

Comment: Javapns does not implement command 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting back a an error code from APNS, the connection should be dropped at that point and APNS will ignore everything after the error.  When you receive an error back, the identifier is the identifier you are currently using a random number for.

There's no easy solution here -- you have to rearchitect what you have so that when you receive the error, you can figure out everything after that point and resend -- I'd recommend using a sequential number for the Identifier and then storing the packets in a queue that you purge periodically (you have to keep them around for say 30 seconds to guarantee that Apple Accepted them).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are writing a single notification to `bao`, so why do you expect it to push multiple alerts? If you want to push multiple alerts, you have to repeat that sequence of bytes that you write into `bao` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have an outer loop that call this piece of code multiple time. outputStream stays open.

Comment: @user2831513 Do you try to read the error response from the socket? It's possible you are sending an invalid device token (if the 2nd notification you sent has an invalid token, it would explain why only the first one is delivered).

Comment: Yes, I get back error-code 8 ( Invalid token ) but the token is valid. If I interchange the tokens, only the first device get the push.

Comment: Are you sure you identified the invalid device token that the 8 error response referred to, based on the notification identifier? Since you don't seem to store the identifier anywhere (you just write `random.nextInt()` to the byte array), how do you know which device token is invalid?

Comment: Currently I'm not using Notification identifier but I would log it. While testing, after sending the first alert, I would receive an empty error responce, but on the second, I would receive the error together with the last generated id. In addition to looking at the log, I have the two devices to confirm receipt of notification.

Comment: @user2831513 Do you get an error response on the second even after changing the order? That doesn't make sense (if a token is invalid, it remains invalid, regardless whether you send it first or second).

Comment: Yes.. Only the second. I suspected It might be how I am writing frame length but not sure.

Comment: Where do you get `deviceTokenAsBytes` from? Are you sure it's 32 bytes?

Comment: Yes.. I generate it Here is the code      byte[] deviceTokenAsBytes = new byte[32];
   deviceToken = deviceToken.toUpperCase();
   int j = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < deviceToken.length(); i += 2) {
    String t = deviceToken.substring(i, i + 2);
    int tmp = Integer.parseInt(t, 16);
    deviceTokenAsBytes[j++] = (byte) tmp;
   }

Comment: Apple closes the connection if you get any error at all.  So when you get the code 8 from them, anything you send/sent after that is dropped on the floor.

Comment: I agree.. The issue is that I cannot tell what is causing the error. Is it they way I am creating the frame or the way I am writing the bytes? not sure

Answer (score 1):

The command 2 and the frame data length applies to each message. If you send multiple messages in one connection, then for each message: send command 2, the message's frame data length, and the 5 parts (token, payload, id, expiry, priority)

Comment: Does the framelength needs to be 32 bit unsigned big endian?