# How to create bytes in Java to send payload to APNS

Tags: java, ios, byte, apple-push-notifications

I need to build a APNS provider program for my app.
I was previously using PHP to do this trick and everything's been working fine thanks to the abstraction offered by dear PHP.
But now I have to handle this task in Java. I do not want to use 3-rd party library in my code-base since I really need total control and customization. While I am trying I quickly find It becoming way more bare-metal.
I barely know how to work with bytes in java. I searched on Google for quite a while only to find that the information about building APNS provider in Java is amazingly rare considering popularity of Java.

To be specific:
I got device token as String deviceToken. And payload in String(JSON format) payload.
How do I write them to outputStream to be in line with binary format required by Apple?

Thanks guys!

Comment: There are some APNS libraries in Java (JavaPNs, java-apns). You can take a look at their code for examples how to write the binary format.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096785/new-command-2-apple-push-notification-not-sending-multiple-alerts/) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you wanted to recreate the wheel, but you can check this source codes:

https://code.google.com/p/javapns/source/browse/trunk/src/javapns/communication/ConnectionToAppleServer.java

https://code.google.com/p/javapns/source/browse/trunk/src/javapns/notification/Payload.java (this is the actual payload)

In any case, instead of rebuilding everything you can download the project and extend some classes for specific things you want to do. But as far as I know, that lib is pretty much complete, I used it in 2 projects and it works pretty well.