# Sending APNS command = 2

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I've got a problem sending level 2 notifications to APNS. The v1 are sending ok, but I'd like to move to v2. Below are my two methods that implement both versions. I separated these from the rest of the code to easily change between the two. The v1 works, while the v2 does not..

```
static function createNotificationV1($token, $payload, $id, $expireTime)
{
    $msg = pack('C', 1); // v1
    $msg .= pack('N', $id); // id
    $msg .= pack('N', $expireTime);
    $msg .= pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $token);
    $msg .= pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    return $msg;
}

static function createNotificationV2($token, $payload, $id, $expireTime)
{
    $tokenItem = pack('C', 1) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $token);
    $payloadItem = pack('C', 2) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $idItem = pack('C', 3) . pack('n', 4) . pack('N', $id);
    $expireItem = pack('C', 4) . pack('n', 4) . pack('N', $expireTime);
    $priorityItem = pack('C', 5) . pack('n', 1) . pack('C', 10);

    $frame = $tokenItem . $payloadItem . $idItem . $expireItem . $priorityItem;

    $msg = pack('C', 2); // v2
    $msg .= pack('n', strlen($frame));
    $msg .= $frame;

    return $msg;
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have u found any solution for this, I am also searching for command 2 work out, if so please post it!

Comment: Not yet, but I only just posted this.. Please upvote this question to maybe draw more attention to it :-)

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096785/new-command-2-apple-push-notification-not-sending-multiple-alerts)

Comment: Related, but doesn't answer it I think.. His code seems to be working, while mine isn't sending anything. I don't really see the difference between the two. Maybe I'm missing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is working great:

```
$pn = pack('CnH*', 1, 32, $token)
    . pack('CnA*', 2, strlen($payload), $payload)
    . pack('CnA*', 3, 4, $id)
    . pack('CnN',  4, 4, $expireTime)
    . pack('CnC',  5, 1, 10);

$msg = pack('CN', 2, strlen($pn)) . $pn;
```

Because your are using `pack('n', strlen($frame))` instead of `pack('N',`

Comment: Awesome, that was indeed the problem! I was setting the frame length as a short instead of a long. Thanks very much :-)

Comment: I think the A* for the $id line is incorrect though, that is only a 4 byte value, so you'd want to encode the id as a long, rather than space-padded string.

Comment: @Pvel I'm using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4) to generate the identifier. You can also use a long, I think both are correct. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) "An arbitrary, opaque value that identifies this notification."

Comment: Ah, fair enough. That'd work indeed, although I don't think you have a guarantee of uniqueness with that method? Either way, Apple doesn't care, they just bounce back whatever you used as id if they found a problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$pn = pack('CnH*', 1, 32, $sDeviceToken)
  . pack('CnA*', 2, strlen($sPayload), $sPayload)
  . pack('CnN', 3, 4, $nMessageID)
  . pack('CnN', 4, 4, $nExpire > 0 ? time() + $nExpire : 0)
  . pack('CnC', 5, 1, $priority);

$sRet = pack('CN', self::COMMAND_PUSH, strlen($pn)) . $pn;
```

The line $id have a mistake not CnA*, It need CnN